# How to route in Route53 from non-WWW to WWW?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've seen all the solutions for this kind of questions, but they are all related with S3 bucket solutions. These solutions does not fit my issue, because I don't see how S3 bucket is related with it.

Anyway, I have a domain name `www.example.com`. I use an `A Record` to route it to my ALB. Works fine.
By now, I had some configuration for `example.com` (routed via `A Record` to ALB).
But this practice is considered bad because SEO considers these 2 domains as 2 different pages.

So What I need is to redirect(?) `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

I tried configure `PTR` Routing type on `example.com` to `www.example.com` but that's just doesn't work. When I do so I get "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

What is the correct way to do so?

Comment: is example.com is hosted zone in route 53? if yes there might 2 default records for the zone right?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yes it is an hosted zone

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can also create a CNAME record with host as www and value is your LB or IP.

Regards